# Help creating a graph?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions

I need help creating a graph that resembles the attached image. I've tried to do so myself using the arctan and $x^{1/3}$ function but my results have been too steep near the center. If I am being unclear please ask for elaboration in the comments, any help I receive is greatly appreciated. Thanks again.[image: what i hope to create]

Comment: Perhaps one of these sigmoid functions would fit the bill? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the logistic function [as defined here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) with $x_0=26$ and $L=100$, and tune $k$ to achieve the desired steepness.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much for the quick response and all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using

\begin{align}
f(x)&=
\frac{1}{\pi}\left(2\arctan(x)+\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)
=
\begin{cases}
-1 & x\le -1
\\
-1..1 & -1\le x\le 1
\\
\phantom{-}1 & x\ge 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

and 
\begin{align}
f_d(x)&=f(x)\,\exp(1-|f(x)|),
\end{align}

plot $a+b\,f_d((x-d)/d)$.

For example, for $a=50, b=40, d=26$ we have

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Thanks so much for the quick response!